# How can I randomly generate a unique, unused object name

Tags: r

I need to generate temporary variable name, that will never clash with any existing variable in the current global environment.

The variable will store data that I cannot fetch in one step with [ExcelSi-R](http://sourceforge.net/p/excelsir/wiki/User%20Documentation/), such as lists.

Comment: Presumably this is happening inside a function, so why does it matter if it clashes with a name in the global environment?

Comment: @Gregor the problem is that it does not happen inside function... WIth ExcelSi-R I can only tap into the `.GlobalEnv`...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. (Well, makes sense from your POV... not sure that it makes sense for ExcelSi-R...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
temp.name = function(n=4, avoid = ls()) {

  tn = paste(sample(letters, n), collapse="")

  while (tn %in% avoid) {
    tn = paste(sample(letters, n), collapse="")
  }

  tn
}

temp.name()
```